# Find values that do not exist in a table

Tags: sql, oracle

Say I have a table:

```
ID   ACCNT   DESC
1    123     aaa
2    234     bbb
3    345     ccc
```

I have a list of account numbers 123,345,555,777.
So I can get a list that exist by

```
SELECT * FROM MY_TABLE WHERE ACCNT IN (...my list...)
```

Now I want to accomplish the opposite.
From my list I want a query to show me the account numbers that are not in the table.

So in my example I want to report that 555 and 77 does not exist in the table.

How can I write this query in Oracle SQL?

Comment: Does this list exist in a table?

Comment: I guess, you have another table or list for the account numbers. Share it, otherwise it isn't possible to show.

Comment: Where your list of numbers is coming from?

Comment: I was given a list of id's. They do not exist in a table.  I need to report back what id's in that list that do not exist in the table.

Comment: I think you will need either a table, a temporary table, or some dynamic SQL to get the result you want.

Comment: So you'd need to manually hard code them in a query?

Comment: Yes.  This is a one time occurrence.

Comment: @NicholasKrasnov Yes, or create a table which contains those values, which you could then left join

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
select column_value as missing_num
from   table (sys.odcinumberlist (123,345,555,777))
where  column_value not in (select accnt from my_table);
```

Comment: To do the same with a list of strings use `sys.odcivarchar2list` in place of `sys.odcinumberlist`
And if "my_table" is a large table the following is faster:
`select column_value as missing_num
from   table(sys.odcivarchar2list('abc','cde','def')) t
where  not exists (select 1 from my_table where my_table.accnt = t.column_value);`

Answer (score 2):

The following approach might work on Oracle.  You can create a subquery using `UNION` which has a single column containing your list of account IDs.  Then you can `LEFT JOIN` this to your table and isolate the IDs which do not match to anything in `MY_TABLE`.

```
SELECT t1.ACCNT
FROM
(
    SELECT 123 AS ACCNT FROM DUAL
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 345 FROM DUAL
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 555 FROM DUAL
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 777 FROM DUAL
) t1
LEFT JOIN MY_TABLE t2
    ON t1.ACCNT = t2.ACCNT
WHERE t2.ACCNT IS NULL
```

One advantage of this approach is that it does not actually create a table which you might not want around after the query.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the source of your list of account numbers. For example, you could use a collection type and the TABLE operator:

```
-- Test case setup
CREATE TABLE ACCNT(ID,ACCNT,DESCR) AS
SELECT 1,123, 'aaa' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2,234, 'bbb' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3,345, 'ccc' FROM DUAL;

-- Create a collection type to hold account numbers
CREATE TYPE tab_numbers AS TABLE OF NUMBER;
/

-- Select account numbers that does not occur on the table
SELECT *
  FROM TABLE(TAB_NUMBERS(123,345,555,777))
 WHERE COLUMN_VALUE NOT IN (SELECT ACCNT FROM ACCNT);
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way to do it. You can simply create a schema-level collection(nested table) and use right/left outer join:

```
-- our collection type
create type t_list as table of number;
/

-- sample of data from your question
with t1(id1, accnt, desc1) as(
  select 1, 123, 'aaa' from dual union all
  select 2, 234, 'bbb' from dual union all
  select 3, 345, 'ccc' from dual
)
-- query itself
select t2.column_value as missing_num
  from t1                               <-- here goes your table
  right join table(t_list(123,345,555,777)) t2
     on (t2.column_value = t1.accnt)
  where t1.accnt is null
```

Result:

```
MISSING_NUM
-----------
        555
        777

2 rows selected.
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `WHERE NOT EXISTS`, example provided below;

```
SELECT *
FROM MY_TABLE MT 
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM AccountNumbers AN WHERE MT.accountID = AN.id)
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it can be using a unpivot function:

```
select Number as ACCNT from(
select * from (
select 123,345,555,777 from dual ) 
unpivot
(
  "Values" FOR "Number" IN ("123","235","555","777")
 ) 
 ) 
minus

select ACCNT from my_table ;
```

The output should be the account numbers which are left from your list.