# Return the values that do not exist in the table but do exist in my IN list?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, azure-sql-database

**Environment**

I have a table named DEVICE that contains 3 rows:

```
DeviceID | Number
1          1111111111111111111
2          2222222222222222222
3          4444444444444444444
```

Using SSMS I query an Azure SQL table for 3 rows using an IN list:

```
select number from device 
where number in
(
'1111111111111111111',
'2222222222222222222',
'3333333333333333333',
)
```

Result:

```
NUMBER
1111111111111111111
2222222222222222222
```

Great that works as expected:

- 3 rows in table.
- 2 rows returned from my IN list
- 1 row not returned that is not in my IN list.

**Question**

How do I query to return the NUMBERS that DO NOT exist in the table but DO exist in my IN list?  (ideally using IN if possible).

Expected result:

```
NUMBER
3333333333333333333
```

Important to note the IN list in my production environment contains:

- 8366 rows in the IN list.
- Rows returned in production database 7225 of the 8366 exist in the table.
- Therefore 1141 are missing. Its these values I need.
- Production table contains 80,000 rows in total.

**Testing**

1. `NOT EXISTS` attempted but no rows are returned in the result set at all.

   ```
   select number from device 
   where NOT EXISTS
   (
   SELECT number FROM DEVICE WHERE number IN
   (
   '1111111111111111111',
   '2222222222222222222',
   '3333333333333333333',
   --(etc followed by 8366 unique values)    
   )
   )
   ```

   Result:

   ```
   NUMBER
   (null)
   ```

   Expected to see the value 3333333333333333333 as it does not exist in my table.
2. `LEFT JOIN` is not helpful as there are not other tables to join.
3. `NOT IN` returned values that are in the database table but are not in my `IN` source list.

   Result:

   ```
   NUMBER
   4444444444444444444
   ```
4. I have also considered creating a TEMP table, inserting my IN list values and running a LEFT join on the NUMBER. I need to proceed cautiously here as its a production environment.
5. Trying this too from another stack post but struggling:

   ```
   select column_value as missing_num
   from   table (sys.odcinumberlist (123,345,555,777))
   where  column_value not in (select accnt from my_table);
   ```

**Ref**

A)

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Device](
[DeviceID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[Number] [varchar](20) NULL,

CONSTRAINT [Device_PK] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
[DeviceID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF,     
ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON)
)

GO
```

B)
[Find values that do not exist in a table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40266354/find-values-that-do-not-exist-in-a-table)

Thank you.

Comment: You seem to be having trouble with a [correlated subquery](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187638(v=sql.105).aspx). In your **Testing 1** example, the inner `SELECT` runs and determines if there are _any_ rows in the specified set. If not, the `NOT EXISTS` is satisfied and _all_ rows will be returned from `device` since there is no correlation between the subquery and the outer query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Constructing an `IN` statement with 8,366 different values is *not* efficient.  This essentially results in 8,366 different `OR` statements in your query.

For something like this, I recommend using a temp table and inserting your values into that, then using a `JOIN` to it.  In this specific case, you should use a [`LEFT JOIN`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187518(v=sql.105).aspx) to that table and take only those values that are not found.

For example:

```
Declare @Numbers Table (Number Varchar (20));

Insert  @Numbers
Values  ('1111111111111111111'),
        ('2222222222222222222'),
        ('3333333333333333333'),
        ...

Select      N.Number
From        @Numbers    N
Left Join   Device      D   On  N.Number = D.Number 
Where       D.Number Is Null
```

You can also use a `CTE` to build your list of numbers as well:

```
;With Numbers (Number) As
(
    Select  '1111111111111111111' Union All
    Select  '2222222222222222222' Union All
    Select  '3333333333333333333' Union All
    ...
)
Select      N.Number
From        Numbers     N
Left Join   Device      D   On  N.Number = D.Number 
Where       D.Number Is Null
```

Comment: Your `left join` tables are inverted

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza Ah, you're right, was thinking about it backwards.

Comment: `OUTER JOIN` ??? And I wouldnt use `RIGHT JOIN` unless have to.  Left Join is more common and easy to read in my opinion.

Comment: Eh, understandable, though that mostly comes down to personal preference.  I can update it to use `LEFT JOIN` over `RIGHT JOIN`.

Comment: With the help of excel to format the list:
="("&"'"&A1&"'"&")"&","

And the addition of COLLATE to the RIGHT JOIN:
Right Join  @Numbers    N   On  N.Number collate  Latin1_General_CS_AS = Device.Number collate  Latin1_General_CS_AS
That worked perfectly. Thank you so much. Wish I had asked this question days ago, would have saved me hours. All the best.

Comment: "The number of row value expressions in the INSERT statement exceeds the maximum allowed number of 1000 row values."
I can break in down into 8 queries though.